# Safari browser is launched and disappeared immediately while running automation(testing)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safari, webdriver, testng-eclipse, safaridriver

I am using selenium 3.x.x(eclipse)with java 11 to launch Safari for my testing.
While running the test, Safari browser is launched and disappeared immediately(some time it launch for while and disappeared). Also in console I can see my test is still running until I ended manually.

Could any one please provide some input on this. Moreover it not throwing any error so it is difficult find the root cause.

I have enabled auto remote testing in developer menu but still issue is occurring.